# How would I go about getting a json file into javascipt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, import

I'm extremely new to javascript, so assume I know nothing.
I'm trying to import this json file into my website, and having issues getting it working.
Currently, I'm trying out jquery's `$.getJSON()` method, but it returns with this error code:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///C:/Users/edgib102/Documents/GitHub/First-Website/data.json. (Reason: CORS request not http).`

I tried looking online about it but nothing useful came up, so here I am.
Any help at all would be much appreciated, I've been stuck on this for 2 days now and it's brought my progress to a standstill.

[Github](https://github.com/edgib102/edgib102.github.io/tree/page-2)

[image: Js]

[image: json]

[image: html]

[image: error]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - post CODE, not PICTURES of code.

Comment: @mplungjan alright, noted. thanks for that, will take that into account next time (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot import a JSON file in a script tag
2. You cannot AJAX a JSON file from file system - if you can upload the files to the same webserver (could be a locally run server), then you CAN AJAX it - NOTE the server needs to send correct CORS headers if the server has a different ORIGIN (for example port number)
3. Alternatively change the JSON file to a JS file:

   ```
   const data = { "object-data": { 
       your data 
     }
   };
   ```

and then import it using

```
<script src="data.js"></script>
```

Comment: so, how would I upload to my local system? I'm just running the .hml file off vs code with this URL: file:///C:/Users/edgib102/Documents/GitHub/First-Website/index.html

Comment: save the js file in the same place as index.html like where you have data.json now

Answer (score 1):

This issue is because of safety.
Because of a security reason you cannot import a Json file in to your code because it contains data that could have some effects on the websites.

Your error caused by :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
```

You can use Jquery and ajax to import it.

Step1: use jquery CDN

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

Step2:

```
$.getJSON('dataenter code here.json', function(data) {
    //do stuff with your data here
});
```

good luck :)

Comment: Except the file has to live on a web server, not on local file system

Comment: @mplungjan I know, but you can not import it like a script ...

Comment: I know. That is the whole point of the question

Comment: @mplungjan yeah, I got what is your question point. I'm just saying that you should use ajax and your file should be live on a web server but you can not import the file as a script file ...

Comment: @RaymondShafiee so, I would have to upload the json file somewhere to make it work?

Comment: @mplungjan No, I think there is a misunderstanding. A live Web server could be your local host web server or an online server somewhere on internet ...
Here you should put your file on your local host web server. in a real situation  you should upload it on your web server ...

but right now you have to put the JSON file on your localhost then give its address to the getJSON function !

Comment: OP does not USE a webserver. If the protocole is file:/// then ajax will not work: _I'm just running the .hml file off vs code with this URL: file:///C:/Users/edgib102/Documents/GitHub/First-Website/index.html_

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71005105/295783)

Comment: @EdenGibson No, I think there is a misunderstanding. A live Web server could be your local host web server or an online server somewhere on internet ... Here you should put your file on your local host web server. in a real situation you should upload it on your web server ... but right now you have to put the JSON file on your localhost then give its address to the getJSON function !

Comment: thanks man, I tried that but it brings up a whole other league of issues that I might as well start up a new StackOverflow post. I'll just go with @mplungjan 's answer about using the js file as a replacement (: